# Grunt Assemble Cannot Read Property 'Stage'

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, assemble

Running a pretty simply Assemble task on a project, but I'm getting the following error on my default `grunt` task:

`Running "assemble:site" (assemble) task
Warning: Cannot read property 'stage' of undefined Use --force to continue.`

Currently running (via package.json):

`"assemble": "^0.4.41"
"grunt": "^0.4.5",`

The assemble task in my Gruntfile:

```
assemble: {
    options: {
        assets: '<%= site.assets %>',
        flatten: true,
        production: false,

        // Metadata
        pkg: '<%= pkg %>',
        site: '<%= site %>',

        // Template Config
        partials: '<%= site.includes %>',
        layoutdir: '<%= site.layouts %>',
        layout: '<%= site.layout %>'
    },
    site: {
        files: {'<%= site.root %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/pages/*.hbs']}
    }
},
```

If it helps, here is my config.yml file too:

```
# =============================================
# Build config
# =============================================

# Root Distribution
root:        _gh_pages

# Templates
templates:        templates
includes:         <%= site.templates %>/includes/*.hbs
layouts:          <%= site.templates %>/layouts  
layout:           default.hbs

# Assets Dir
assets:     <%= site.root %>/assets

# =============================================
# Site metadata 
# =============================================

title:      Feast Finder
```

Comment: Appears to be an issue with latest release: https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/541

Answer (score 2):

`cd` into [PROJECT]/node_modules/assemble and run `npm install resolve-dep@0.4.1`

This is a temporary fix, as described [here](http://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/541).

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by Assemble team.